# Play and/or Rip a music CD within a Windows Store Application?

Tags: c#, audio, windows-runtime, audio-player

Is there any way to Play and/or Rip a music CD within a Windows Store Application? Information and documentation seem very light on this subject.

I found this for desktop C# apps:
[Ripping a CD to mp3 in C# - third party component or api out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185209/ripping-a-cd-to-mp3-in-c-sharp-third-party-component-or-api-out-there)
... however I can't use the COM interface IWMPCdromRip within a Windows Store Application (that I know of).

I have also looked at the following API, but it returns a 0-length list of folders with an Audio CD inserted.

```
var folders = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
```

Comment: +1 for good question and showing what you've already tried. Interested to see the answer to this myself.

Comment: Any luck trying with the `MediaElement`? Maybe there's deeply buried support for reading `CDA` files from a CD-ROM... (but it seems unlikely that it would be prioritized). Audio tracks aren't really "files" in the way that would likely be listed in an API call like `GetFoldersAsync`

Comment: I have tried MediaElement and cda files - no joy. Can't believe Microsoft overlooked this simple requirement...